# Waiting for an element to load identifying element with CSS Selector

Tags: python, css, selenium, delay

I am trying to wait for a few elements in a page to load before continuing with entering/getting data from the page. Some reading has lead me to this kind of code:

```
#including imports in case they are influencing things
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get('example.com')
try:
    element1_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'id'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element1_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print('Timed out waiting for page to load')
#Then get some data from example.com
```

This works just fine, however, I'd like to determine if the element is present through CSS Selector, not ID. Reference to Selenium documentation is confusing me. It states that the `presence_of_element_located` method should take a "locator" as an argument, but looking at the `By` documentation, I do not see how `(By.ID, 'id')` is a valid locator (though clearly, it works, and I don't understand this), and more specifically, I don't see how to code it to be a CSS Selector locator.

I have attempted `By.cssSelector`, `By.CSS`, and other similar terms in place of `By.ID`, and moving parentheses about, but I am always returned:

```
AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'cssSelector'
```

Or something similar. I'm clearly missing some documentation somewhere, because I can't figure out why `ID` is a valid attritube for `By` and `cssSelector` isn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use `By.CSS_SELECTOR`.

---

For your [reference](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), here are the attributes available for the `By` class:

```
ID = "id"
XPATH = "xpath"
LINK_TEXT = "link text"
PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
NAME = "name"
TAG_NAME = "tag name"
CLASS_NAME = "class name"
CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```